# Clear setInterval and prevent from glitching out

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I want to know if there is a way to restart/clear the setInterval(); function in Javascript?  My problem is, when you go here:: http://jsfiddle.net/GqrRx/2/ (sorry it doesn't want to work here)... but if you go there and input a date, it works fine. But if you enter in another date, the seconds, minutes, and hours glitch up, and flicker.  I think I need to find a way to restart the interval or stop it.

I tried putting this at the top of my function, but it didn't seem to do anything.

```
clearInterval(runSeconds);
clearInterval(runMinutes);
clearInterval(runHours);
```

I also tried this:

```
var secInt = setInterval(runSeconds, 1000);
var minInt = setInterval(runMinutes, 60000);
var hInt = setInterval(runHours, 3600000);
clearInterval(secInt);
clearInterval(minInt);
clearInterval(hInt);
```

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how this should work, but it would probably be best to use one timer.

Answer (score 1):

Set the result of `setInterval` to a variable, and pass that variable into `clearInterval`.

Something like this:

```
var interval = setInterval(someFunc, 100);
clearInterval(interval);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2Fwindow.setInterval#Example for more information.

Comment: Your fiddle doesn't work for me in the first place, however I believe you are setting the interval and clearing in the wrong scope.  Be sure to define the `var interval` in a scope that both `setInterval` and `clearInterval` can access it.  For your fiddle example, don't put it inside `calcAge()`, define it outside.